# BigQuery equivalent of COALESCE()?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm in the process of converting some aggregate queries from Postgres to our new architecture in BigQuery.  Is there an equivalent of COALESCE() in BigQuery?

Currently, I am converting a Postgres query statement like

```
coalesce(column1,'DEFAULT')
```

to

```
CASE
  WHEN column1 IS NOT NULL
     THEN column1
   ELSE 'DEFAULT'
END AS column1
```

which seems easy enough.

However converting a Postgres query statement with nested coalesce statements like

```
 count(distinct coalesce(
                coalesce(
                coalesce(column1,column2),
                                 column3),
                                 column4)))
```

would get much more messy if I used `CASE` statements all over the place, and also seems like the wrong thing to do.

Does BigQuery have a method equivilent to `COALESCE()`, or am I stuck writing the whole `CASE` statement equivalent?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use IFNULL function in BigQuery, which can be nested like that:

```
select ifnull(column1,
              ifnull(column2,'DEFAULT')) 
from 
(select string(NULL) as column1, 'y' as column2)
```

P.S. But omission of COALESCE in BigQuery is an oversight, I will fix it.

**Update:** As of 4/16/2015, COALESCE is available in BigQuery.
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#conditional_expressions

Comment: Thank you, that seems to work out.

Any idea of when the `COALESCE()` function would be implemented into BigQuery?

Comment: It is implemented as of today :)

Comment: but not documented ? Can't find anydocumentation to it @MoshaPasumansky

Comment: It is documented here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#conditional_expressions